# Sum of the coefficients of polynomial $f(x)= (3x-2)^{107} (x+1)^4$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Sum of the coefficients of polynomial $f(x)= (3x-2)^{107}  (x+1)^4$

Please hint me with this. I can't manage anything except taking 3 common from first bracket.

Comment: Almost the same as:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387222/finding-the-sum-of-the-coefficients-of-polynomial-of-degree-21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that the sum of the coefficients of a polynomial $P(x)$ is $P(1)$.